# Stop ITask in different Form

Tags: multithreading, delphi, task

I have a form that open a second Form.

On the second Form I start a Task. This Form is Free on close, and I need to test with a global var that this Task is assigned and not canceled otherwise I get a Exception because the task was Free.

Does it's exist a better way to do it ? Maybe without any global var ?

```
// [...]

type
  TfrmTest = class(TForm)
    nbRun: TNumberBox;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FTaskNumber: ITask;

    procedure RunTaskNumber;
  end;

// [...]

procedure TfrmTest.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if Assigned(FTaskNumber) then
    FTaskNumber.Cancel;

  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;

procedure TfrmTest.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FTaskNumber := nil;
end;

procedure TfrmTest.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RunTaskNumber;
end;

procedure TfrmTest.RunTaskNumber;
begin
  FTaskNumber := TTask.Run(procedure
                           var
                             i: integer;
                           begin
                             i := 0;

                             while Assigned(FTaskNumber) and (FTaskNumber.Status <> TTaskStatus.Canceled) do
                             begin
                               Sleep(2000);
                               TInterlocked.Increment(i);

                               if Assigned(FTaskNumber) and (FTaskNumber.Status <> TTaskStatus.Canceled) then
                               begin
                                 TThread.Queue(nil, procedure
                                                    begin
                                                      nbRun.Value := i;
                                                    end);
                               end;
                             end;
                           end);
end;

end.
```

Comment: No sure I understand clearly what you intend to do. Anyway, if you use OnCloseQuery event, you have a chance to cancel closing the form when you check the task is still running. Does it helps? If not, explain better what you want to do.

Comment: I let the user close the form yhen he want, I have just have to be sure the thread don't raise an exception. For that I use the global var, need to store it, and check if assigned and not canceled. I find this a little heavy, can I use a CurrentTask or something like that directly on my task ? May be add my form to owner and check if it exist ?

Comment: Task reference needs to be stored somewhere. So you need some storage that will keep IOtlTaskControl alive. It can be a global variable or it can reside on another form (main form).